# How to apply preprocessing in carets train() to only some variables?

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to use caret's super convenient way of preprocessing in the train function, in order to have the same manipulations available for later predictions. However, I want to apply preprocessing to only **some** of the numeric columns. How can I specify this? Can I somehow use the preProcOptions parameter in trainControl?

If I use the normal preProcess object I can do:

```
preObj <- preProcess(training[,"SomeCol"], method=c("scale"))
preData <- predict(preObj, training[,"SomeCol"])
```

But I have no clue how I can achieve the same with train() and trainControl():

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 1, preProcOptions = list(x=x[,"SomeCol"]))
fit <- train(y ~ ., data = training, method = "rf", trControl = ctrl, preProcess=c("scale"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate to mention this but there is an *undocumented* and **not fully tested** way that you can do this

```
> pp <- preProcess(iris, method = list(center = "Petal.Width", scale = names(iris)[1:2]))
> pp
Created from 150 samples and 4 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (1)
  - ignored (1)
  - scaled (2)

> predict(pp, head(iris))
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1     6.158928    8.029986          1.4  -0.9993333  setosa
2     5.917402    6.882845          1.4  -0.9993333  setosa
3     5.675875    7.341701          1.3  -0.9993333  setosa
4     5.555112    7.112273          1.5  -0.9993333  setosa
5     6.038165    8.259414          1.4  -0.9993333  setosa
6     6.521218    8.947698          1.7  -0.7993333  setosa
> head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I haven't tested all of the edge cases of combinations of methods yet, so please do some testing if you choose to use this.

Comment: This approach works fine when I want to apply this preprocessing once before model training. However, I want to have the same preprocessing available for any later predictions of the model in production (i.e. new row of data -> load trained model -> apply same preprocessing as used for model training -> predict Y). Thus, I need to integrate it somehow into caret::train(). I tried train(..., preProcess=list(scale="Petal.Width")), but it doesn't work here

Comment: @Malte I have the same problem.. did you ever find a solution?